# phpunit - fake api response or real response connecting to service?

Tags: php, phpunit, guzzle

I have created a few methods in a service class to connect to external service/provider via Guzzle using API POST Request.

I like to use phpunit for testing - should I use fake the HTTP Json response without connecting to a service or should it connect to a service to get real response from service?

Comment: Mocking the service allows you to return a variety of responses, especially ones difficult to test (such as errors).

Comment: @NigelRen You should answer with more detail and how to mock the service

Comment: If you had some code, it may help, don't know what to answer.  Try looking through http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/testing/unit-testing.html.

Comment: Do you like fast tests? Do you like slow, unreliable tests?

Comment: @localheinz reliable tests

Comment: Is it a service you own, or is it an external service? That's important.

Comment: @localheinz I don't own.  external service

Comment: @localheinz well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common tenet in testing is "Don't mock what you don't own". Mocking those API-calls makes your tests less reliable and will give you a false sense of security as you will likely get *false positives*.

For example when the API unexpectedly introduces a breaking change your tests will be green and once you deploy to production you will finally notice that something is wrong. This is probably what you want your tests to catch.

When you test against the real API you will get a sense of reliability. Do your tests often fail due to service outages or timeouts? If so you can introduce measure like a retry-mechanism, circuit breakers or decoupling the API calls from the rest of your application.

When you mock the API all you can tell is that your code behaves according to a (possibly outdated) specification of the service. That is ok, but not nearly as useful as relying on the actual service.

What you could do is use groups to run those tests separately. This will make it easy to include/exclude these possibly slow and sometimes flaky tests from your remaining tests. This also helps around rate limiting, e.g. by only running those tests on critical branches.

Comment: You have made very good point about test against the real API. During production - Is there a way to run a test every x hour automatically - that will ensure me that the real API service is still working?

Comment: Yes, I know places where they run tests against the production system on intervals in addition to doing branch based testing. You just have to be careful to somehow mark the data to be able to discern them from real data, especially when doing e-commerce. You can set up scheduled jobs with Jenkins for example and then use a special X-TEST-header in the request that is recognised by your application.

Comment: You could also do this with cron jobs running the test suite if your CI/CD-server does not easily support scheduled jobs. Again, if you do this be careful, e.g. with operations that change database state (or worse clean up the database). I recommend having a separate test suite for this to reduce risks of harmful side effects.

Comment: Isn't this a case of using the tools properly though.  Any tool which is relied on to solve all your problems is probably not the right thing.  It's also a case of having to update tests when things change - something which happens internally and externally. This can also help in finding where breakages have happened - libraries are not infallible.  This is why  being able to test each layer to check if it's working 'as expected' is invaluable - even if the 'as expected' is in fact wrong.

Comment: Absolutely @NigelRen. It's perfectly valid to just ensure that just your end of the code works as specified. Nothing stops you from writing both the fast (unit) tests against a mock and the slow acceptance test against the real api either. Then you can decide when to run each test. All of these approaches have trade offs and you have to decide what is important to you. For me this usually depends on whether the API is developed in house, how critical it is for my application, e.g. will it break checkout if it's not working correctly, and how much I trust the API to be stable/not break BC.

Comment: Not being able to reliably reproduce some of the edge cases as you suggest in your comment is for example a perfectly valid thing to test through a mocked API. Sure, it might change and the test might give you a false positive, but assuming this is not some default behavior this might not be as important as making sure that if this invalid/edge case-response is handled correctly.

Comment: Edge cases are a pain to deal with, and usually difficult to predict. 
 Trying to get a live environment to behave badly usually gets managers and clients a bit worried and paperwork coming out of my ears.  So something I've only ever been able to simulate.  Generally agree with what your saying though, just as usual it's about getting the right balance.

Comment: This is untrue. If you choose to test vs the actual API you'll be doing it against the dev/test version of that API not the production version so you won't get any peace of mind regarding breaking changes. Your tests should test the rigour of your own code. It is up to the API provider to ensure that their code works properly.

Answer (score 5):

You should mock external API calls. Your tests are intended to test YOUR code not the external API.

Note: Ultimately if you DO use the external API with your tests you will likely be connecting to a test version of the API (different to the live version of the API that your production environment would connect to) so you're not really ensuring the consistency of the API response anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to keep testing a 3rd party remote API whenever you run your own app tests, even if you group/isolate them and don't run them often.

Test your code up to the point of calling the real API, then trigger a mock response. This tells you that all your code is working, and if the API would have been connectable and would have returned a response then everything is fine.

Unit tests are not for testing remote APIs, that is the job of some other area of the site to ensure is up, like server monitoring with it and your app issuing error logs on production when something with the remote API fails.

The chance is so low of running your tests at the time that the remote API has some issue, you will run your tests and the remote API works fine, and you deploy, then next day the remote API fails and no-one is running the tests.

You have to assume the remote API works 99% of the time, and when it doesn't you get an error log that the request timed out or returned a bad response etc. And if the remote only works a low amount of time like 50/60%, it's time to find another service provider.